# Run chrome's console command on page load automatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm watching a course online and it has the option to autoplay the videos but every time a video ends I need to set it to fullscreen again.
To set the vide to fullscreen using console, I can use `document.getElementsByTagName('VIDEO')[0].requestFullscreen()` and I was wondering if it's possible to make that this line be executed alwasys on page load.

Is this even possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) - install a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/), go to the dashboard, press the "+" button to create a new script, and then type in the Javascript you want to execute whenever you load the page.

[image]